# Using Spring Aspects for logging

Tags: java, spring

I'm quite new to the concept of aspects. So, I'm trying to use aspects to print the name of every function that is executed. After looking at a few tutorials, I've got something like this :

```
package com.skyfall.model.slide2;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

@Aspect
public class testAspect {

    @Before("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void log(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("----logBefore is running.-----");
        System.out.println("executing ".concat(joinPoint.getSignature().getName()));

    }
}
```

However, this seems to be having no effect whatsoever.

Edit : Here is the specific class that I'm using :

```
package com.skyfall.model.slide2;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringStyle;

public class CostDto {

    private String text;
    private int value;
    private static final String RUPEES = "Rs.";
    private static final String SPACE_DELIMITTER = " ";

    public CostDto(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        this.value = getValueFromText(text);
    }

    public CostDto(int value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.text = getTextFromValue(value);
    }

    public CostDto(String text, int value) {
        this.text = text;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValueFromText(String text) {
        int length = text.length();
        String value = text.substring(0, length - RUPEES.length());
        value = value.trim();
        return Integer.parseInt(value);
    }

    public String getTextFromValue(int value) {
        return String.valueOf(value) + SPACE_DELIMITTER + RUPEES;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, ToStringStyle.SHORT_PREFIX_STYLE);
    }
}
```

And this is the JUnit test :

```
package com.skyfall.model.slide2;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import com.skyfall.persistence.base.BaseControllerTest;

public class CostDtoTest extends BaseControllerTest {

    private CostDto cost1;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        cost1 = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void testValueConstructor() {
        cost1 = new CostDto("123 Rs.");
        assertEquals(123, cost1.getValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void testTextConstructor() {
        cost1 = new CostDto(8901);
        System.out.println(cost1.getText());
        assertEquals("8901 Rs.", cost1.getText());
    }

    @Test
    public void testValueAndTextConstructor() {
        cost1 = new CostDto("491 Rs.", 491);
        assertEquals(491, cost1.getValue());
        assertEquals("491 Rs.", cost1.getText());
    }
}
```

The test works just fine, and print out "8901 Rs." as expected, but the testAspect doesn't do anything.

Comment: There's more to that than just simply defining an `@Aspect` with a `@Before` pointcut. There is some configuration involved. Can you post what you have so far, configuration-wise?

Comment: You mean, the spring XML files?

Comment: Yes. `@Aspect` annotation by itself doesn't do anything. It needs some "glue code" to make it work.

Comment: I've basically added these two lines, which is all that seemed to be necessary. What "glue code" do I need? <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean id="testAspect" class="com.skyfall.model.slide2.testAspect;" />

Comment: What you posted so far should work. So, there must be something else in your project that doesn't work. Is this web app? Standalone?

Comment: It's a website back end that I'm working on as an intern. While I'm not totally familiar with the whole project, it does seem to be working OK to me. Specifically, all I want to do is print names of functions being called, and I am indeed able to execute public functions.

Comment: Then you need to figure out what more details to provide from your project to allow us to help you. We cannot make suggestions based on non-existent details. What you have provided so far is pretty basic and, as I said, it should work. How did you establish that what you have so far doesn't work? What methods do you expect to be intercepted? (I understand "all public methods", but give some examples from your code)

Comment: Alright, I've edited the question.

Comment: It doesn't do anything because you are doing this: `cost1 = new CostDto(8901);` This means Spring doesn't know about your CostDto instance, because Spring is not the one creating it, you are creating it manually.

Comment: Post the complete source code of your test class.

Comment: Do you have an .xml associated with this test, as well?

Comment: Done. So, how do I get Spring to acknowledge the instance (short of using Spring to create all objects)

Comment: You really need to read the Spring reference documentation, it's a very good source of information for Spring. "acknowledging" the instance means that you need to let Spring create that instance. If you have an .xml configuration for that test you should define the DTO in there and then use `@Autowired` annotation to inject it in your test class. And, as I said, you really need to read the reference documentation.

Comment: I guess this is not as straightforward as it seemed, and I need to learn more before starting coding. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: It's not difficult, but you need some basic understanding of Spring. Good luck!